# C# Threading: Using Monitor.Wait, Lock and PulseAll

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to CSharp and Threading.

To be familiar with Monitor.Wait,Monitor.lock and Monitor.PulseAll,I framed a scenario described below.

*"A FootballGround is being shared by different teams for practicing purpose. At any  time only one team can use the ground for their practice. A team can use the ground for 30 minutes for their practice. Once the time reaches 25 minutes it should signal other threads that the ground is about to free after 5 minutes.When  the ground is wet (enum has three values free,allotted,wet) no team is allowed to lock the ground and all should wait for 10 minutes”*

Honestly speaking, I do not know how turn the description in to actual coding. Based on my understanding I designed the outline.

```
namespace ThreadingSimulation
 {

  // A Random Activity can be picked up from this enum by a team

         public enum RandomGroundStatus
         {
             free,
             allotted,
             Wet          
         }

class FootBallGround
{

    public void Playing(object obj)
    {
      // Here the name of the team which is using the  ground will be printed
      // Once the time is reached to 25 minnutes the active thread acquired
      // the lock will signal  other threads    

    }

   public void GroundCleaningInProgress(object obj)
   {

      // Ground cleaning is in progress all of you
      // wait for 10 minutes

   }

}    




 class Team
   {
     string teamName;  

      static void Main()
      {

        //select random value for GrandStatus from enum

       // if the ground is wet no team is allowed to get the
       // ground for 10 minutes  

        //if the ground is free "Team A" locks the ground

        // otherwise "Team B" locks the ground

      }

   }

}
```

Here I do not know how to apply locks and signalls.kindly help  me .

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559293 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561406

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In reality, your scenario doesn't hugely map to a `lock` - but we'll try anyway ;-p

I've tweaked the setup a bit; instead:

- one entity can have the grounds at a time
- when a team finishes, they tell the first person they see (if anyone is waiting)
- when the cleaner finishes, they are noisy - so *everyone* notices them leave and tries to get on the pitch

Here's the code; note that they don't have the lock when *using* the grounds, as that would prevent other people from joining the queue for `Pulse`.

In reality, we could do *all* of this with *just* `lock` (not using `Pulse` at all), and just use the standard blocking behaviour. But this sample shows `Pulse` and `PulseAll` being used to re-activate threads when a condition is met.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
interface IGroundUser
{
    bool Invoke(); // do your stuff; return true to wake up *everyone*
                   // afterwards, else false
}
class Team : IGroundUser
{
    private readonly string name;
    public Team(string name) { this.name = name; }
    public override string ToString() { return name; }
    public bool Invoke()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": playing...");
        Thread.Sleep(25 * 250);
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": leaving...");
        return false;
    }
}
class Cleaner : IGroundUser
{
    public override string ToString() {return "cleaner";}
    public bool Invoke()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cleaning in progress");
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 250);
        Console.WriteLine("cleaning complete");
        return true;
    }
}
class FootBallGround
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ground = new FootBallGround();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Team("Team A")); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Team("Team B")); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Cleaner()); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Team("Team C")); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Team("Team D")); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ground.UseGrounds(new Team("Team E")); });
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    bool busy;
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public void UseGrounds(IGroundUser newUser)
    {
        // validate outside of lock
        if (newUser == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("newUser");
        // only need the lock when **changing** state
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            while (busy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(newUser + ": grounds are busy; waiting...");
                Monitor.Wait(syncLock);
                Console.WriteLine(newUser + ": got nudged");
            }
            busy = true; // we've got it!
        }
        // do this outside the lock, allowing other users to queue
        // waiting for it to be free
        bool wakeAll = newUser.Invoke();

        // exit the game
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            busy = false;
            // wake up somebody (or everyone with PulseAll)
            if (wakeAll) Monitor.PulseAll(syncLock);
            else Monitor.Pulse(syncLock);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Nice,Impeccable and Ingenious answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

The important thing to always remember with locking and mutithreaded applciations is that locking is only effective if *all* your code that accesses a locked resource plays by the same rules i.e if one thread can lock a resource, all other threads that can access that same resource should use locks before accessing that resource.

**Monitor and Lock**

The `lock` keyword is convenienve wrapper for the `Monitor` class. This means that `lock(obj)` is the same as `Monitor.Enter(obj)` (although `Monitor` has the added functionality to timeout after a period of time if it could not get the lock to the object).

**Pulsing events and threads**

When a number of threads are waiting to gain a lock on some resource, via code you can signal when the owner thread is completed with the resource. This is known as *signalling* or *pulsing* and can be accomplished via `Monitor.Pulse`, `Monitor.PulseAll`, `ManualResetEvent.Set` or even `AutoResetEvent.Set`.

### Soccer Example

So your soccer example below would be coded to include thread locking as follows:

```
 namespace ThreadingSimulation
 {

   // A Random Activity can be picked up from this enum by a team

    public enum RandomGroundStatus
    {
        Free,
        Allotted,
        Wet          
    }

 class FootBallGround
 {
     private Team _currentTeam;

     // Set the initial state to true so that the first thread that 
     // tries to get the lock will succeed
     private ManualResetEvent _groundsLock = new ManualResetEvent(true);

     public bool Playing(Team obj)
     {
       // Here the name of the team which is using the  ground will be printed
       // Once the time is reached to 25 minutes the active thread the lock will
       // signal other threads    
       if (!_groundsLock.WaitOne(10))
         return false;

       _currentTeam = obj;

       // Reset the event handle so that no other thread can come into this method
       _groundsLock.Reset();    

       // Now we start a separate thread to "timeout" this team's lock 
       // on the football grounds after 25 minutes
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitForTimeout(25));                  
     }

    public void GroundCleaningInProgress(object obj)
    {

       // Ground cleaning is in progress all of you wait for 10 minutes

    }

    private void WaitForTimeout(object state)
    {
         int timeout = (int)state;

         // convert the number we specified into a value equivalent in minutes
         int milliseconds = timeout * 1000;
         int minutes = milliseconds * 60;

         // wait for the timeout specified 
         Thread.Sleep(minutes);

         // now we can set the lock so another team can play
         _groundsLock.Set();
     }
 }    

 class Team
  {
      string teamName;  
      FootBallGround _ground;

       public Team(string teamName, FootBallGround ground)
       {
          this.teamName = teamName;
          this._ground = ground;      
       }

       public bool PlayGame()
       {
            // this method returns true if the team has acquired the lock to the grounds
            // otherwise it returns false and allows other teams to access the grounds
            if (!_ground.Playing(this))
               return false;
            else
               return true;
       }
  }


  static void Main()
  {
         Team teamA = new Team();
         Team teamB = new Team();

         // select random value for GrandStatus from enum
         RandomGroundStatus status = <Generate_Random_Status>;

         // if the ground is wet no team is allowed to get the
         // ground for 10 minutes.
         if (status == RandomGroundStatus.Wet)
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitForDryGround);
         else
         {
             // if the ground is free, "Team A" locks the ground
             // otherwise "Team B" locks the ground

             if (status == RandomGroundStatus.Free)
             {
               if (!teamA.PlayGame())
                  teamB.PlayGame();
             }
          }
    }
```

}

** Notes **

- Use `ManualResetEvent` instead of `lock` and `Monitor` since we want direct control of *when* the state of the lock is pulsed to enable other threads to play a game of football.
- Pass in a reference to the `FootBallGrounds` to each `Team` because each team will play on specific foot ball grounds and each football grounds could be occupied by another team
- Pass in a reference to the current team playing on the `FootBallGround` because only one team can be playing on the grounds at a time.
- Use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` since it's more efficient at creating simple threads than us manually creating threads. Ideally we could use a `Timer` instance as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike for Spending your valuable time :)